# Add item to List<> sorts it?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

I have a generic list and have done

```
mylist.Sort(Comparison<TypeA>(delegate(TypeA a, TypeA b)
{ return a.Text.CompareTo(b.Text)) }
```

After the above runs, I do `mylist.Add(someObject)`.  It's `Text` property starts with "T".  There is also an item in the list that starts with `"V"`.  Rather than someObject being added last, it goes just before the item starting with `"V"`.  This makes me think the sort continues to apply.  Is that the case?

If so, how do I add this new item as last?

Comment: Can you add a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: No, this it _not_ the case. `List`s are not naturally sorted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is definitely wrong.  `List<>.Sort` performs the sorting once, and adding additional items will add them to the end.

This behavior is only possible if `mylist` is a `SortedList` or something similar.  If you're not initializing it yourself, you should check the runtime type, because even though the compile-time type might be `IList`, you might be getting a `SortedList`.  But this is very unlikely.